# Python with open statement for openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, with-statement

As you know the file in Python could be open two ways:

```
my_file = open(filename, mode)
data = my_file.read()
```

and

```
with open(filename, mode) as my_file:
data = my_file.read()
```

In first case if program is crashed, the file might not be closed.
Now I'm working on the project using openpyxl. [The documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file) offers the first way only:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')
```

As you can see, in the 2nd case my_file is fileobject. It works this way:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
with open(f_name_xls, 'rb') as f:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f_name_xls)
    ws = wb.active
```

But usually we use fileobject f working with the file, and I don't understand how can I use it in this case.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can write your own context manager.

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl is a Python library for interaction with Excel files in xml format.

You can use mere:

from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')

without **with** statement - all the exceptions will be handled by openpyxl under the hood.

BTW, the "third" way to open the file is to use native Python`s exception handling structure (here I give a primitive example :) ):

```
file = open('file_path', 'w') 
try: file.write('hello world') 
finally: file.close()
```